# How to install mongodb 64 bit ubuntu

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to install the 64 bit version of mongodb. I added the repositories to mongodb.list, but apt-get install installs the 32 bit version by default, how can I alter that?

This is my output

> enygma@enygma-Inspiron-5721:~$ dpkg --print-architecture
>
> i386
>
> enygma@enygma-Inspiron-5721:~$ uname -a
>
> Linux enygma-Inspiron-5721 3.13.0-39-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 28 13:31:23 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: Something appears borked in your OS configuration. What is the output of `dpkg --print-architecture`? Should be "amd64" And does `uname -a` report the OS is 64-bit for that matter. Sounds more like an [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/) question really.

Comment: Edit your question. That is what the link is for. Don't try and paste more information in comments. Almost never works.

Comment: You have a 32-bit machine so you cannot install 64-bit. You need a 64-bit ubuntu install.